# Database Design: Defining Access Control

Tags: database, normalize

An application I am developing needs to provide access to data based on a list of cities defined for each client. A client can have:

- access to all cities in a country OR
- access to all cities in a state / region OR
- access to select cities in any state
  or country.

What would be the best way to define this in the database (if the db has a **Country** table, **State** / **Region** table, **City** table and a **Client** table)?

**Clarification**:
(A simplified view of the tables with only the essential columns pertaining to this question).

Country table -

> idCountry | Name

State table -

> idState | idCountry | Name

City table -

> idCity | idState | Name

Client table -

> idClient | Name

Answer (score 0):

You could to create a `Location` self related table (Id, Name, ParentLocation) and a `AccessControl` table (ClientId, LocationId). When a client is related to a location, you could grant access to all location below it. Some examples:

```
ID Name      Parent
-------------------
 1 World     NULL   -- Need to represent all countries
 2 Brazil    1      -- A country
 3 São Paulo 2      -- A state
 4 São Paulo 3      -- A city
```

If you want to stick your current model, maybe a table like (ClientId, CountryId nullable, StateId nullable, CityId nullable). This way you could define your security access as your definition, but would need to deal with nullable fields.

Comment: I'd prefer if the database design was normalized, and the Location table method would defeat this. Regarding the second method - that was my first thought too - but perhaps there are better solutions? (Thanks.)